# I want handle two independent controllers without broadcasting $rootScope in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller, broadcast

I did that with `broadcast` event into `$rootScope`. Now I am trying to do that without using `$rootScope`. Is that possible ?

Here is the code can check what i did with `$rootScope`

[Example code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8SVpib9bPf9nJyYPB3nU)

Comment: why do you want to do it without rootscope? there are ways to share data between controllers using service as well...but it would be better if we know the reason

Comment: there is no special reason.Only for the knowledge.Is that possible ..?

Comment: yeah it is possible using services, and you can also watch the variable inside controllers instead of broadcasting, but the overall thing would be similar to what you are doing right now, you will generally need some other scope to share data between two independent controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share data between controllers using events always needs a scope that's up the hierarchy of both controller's scopes, because broadcast events bubble down the scope hierarchy from parent to children. Because $rootScope is the topmost scope it is save to use it for broadcasting.
The alternative solution would be to add watch functions to both controllers watching a variable in an injected service. Because services are singletons this would be fine too.